# C# How to investigate why my service is stopping unexpectedly

Tags: c#, exception

My Service works perfectly fine for a random amount of time and then just stops.

I am catching all exceptions that i can see. 
I have added a try/catch around the service creating to try and get some sort of error but im getting nothing. The service just stops.

```
        try
        {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new my_service() };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logEvent(e);   // Log any errors to a .txt file.
        }
```

The event viewer shows the following:

```
Faulting application name: my_service.exe, version: 0.9.2.1, time stamp: 0x50717154
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b96e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00055f99
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

Comment: Can you try attaching visual studio debugger to the service process and wait for the error to occur?

Comment: @CathalMF  Did you make some progress? Did we help you?

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible to guess what went wrong with the information you gave. But you can try to use a trick to catch every uncatched exception, and log it.

Here is how I do in my project:

First, in my Main(), I suscribe to the following event:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
```

And I define the Handler, which just logs the stacktrace to a file and prints it to the console (though it's irrelevant for you since you run your app as a service):

```
private static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e){
        try{
            Logger.Append(Severity.CRITICAL, "Unhandlable error : "+e.ExceptionObject); 


        }catch{}
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandlable error : "+e.ExceptionObject);
        Environment.Exit(10);
    }
```

Comment: This helped me. The problem was that exception occured in "finally" block and that is why I didn`t see it in logs. Don`t be so stupid as I am =/

Answer (score 3):

If your service is up and running, logging around `Run()` won't do you much good, since nothing much executes in that method. It will basically just trigger your service's `OnStart` method.

The normal case is that your service's `OnStart` method starts an entirely new Thread to run the actual service. It's in that Thread you need to do the logging. Putting a try/catch around that Thread's entire threadstart method, or subscribing to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException should give you any exceptions your service is generating and not catching so you can log them.

The problem though (which is hard to know since you're not showing the service's code) seems to be that the service crashes in ntdll.dll, which may be a pinvoke (call to an external native DLL), which means you may not get any exceptions to catch. Debugging native crashes is a totally different science.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a simple console application, referance the assembly, and call the code from  the console app and easily debug it. (easiest option by a long shot).